# Scoping a selector in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm inexperienced with JS and jQuery and have this simple script written to total up some numbers of form inputs within the scope of an h3 into a div in that same scope. But I'm coming up with nothing. Using the Console, I can tell that it's getting the initial values for the keyup event correctly, but when I attempt to get these items within an h3 scope, it comes up with an empty array. Reading the jQuery() docs,

```
 $( 'input#survey_scores_score_item, div.my_group')
```

yields a hash which nicely shows three arrays of these groupings. But also all the individual input items. So clearly, I'm not setting up these query correctly.  How would I set up the scoping so that the individual inputs are not cluttering up the array so I can run the jQuery .each over the groups?

Here is my markup:

```html
<body>    
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/surveys/1" class="edit_survey" id="edit_survey_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"></div>

    <h2>General</h2>
      <h3>Policies and Procedures</h3>
 <div class="my_group">
        <div class="item_enclosure row">
            <div class="item_text small-9 large-9 columns">
                GivEx and Smart Cards being tracked? 
            </div>
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <div class="item_scoring">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item_score item-6 small-6 columns">     
                        <input id="survey_scores_score_item" name="survey[scores][score_item]" placeholder="2" type="text">
                        <input as="hidden" id="survey_scores_inspection_id" name="survey[scores][inspection_id]" type="hidden" value="1">    
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_hiscore item-6 small-6 columns">
                        / 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div> 
        <div class="item_enclosure row">
            <div class="item_text small-9 large-9 columns">
                Change Fund/Petty Cash (810) reviewed daily? 
            </div>
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <div class="item_scoring">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item_score item-8 small-6 columns">     
                        <input id="survey_scores_score_item" name="survey[scores][score_item]" placeholder="5" type="text">
                        <input as="hidden" id="survey_scores_inspection_id" name="survey[scores][inspection_id]" type="hidden" value="1">    
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_hiscore item-8 small-6 columns">
                        / 5
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div> 
              <div class="item enclosure row"> 
                    <div class="item_text total small-9 large-9 columns">
                        Total:
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_scoring item_scoring_total small-3 total columns">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="item_score item_score_total small-6 columns">
                                XX
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_hiscore total small-6 columns">
                                / 7
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
</div>
      <h3>Physical Security</h3>
 <div class="my_group">
        <div class="item_enclosure row">
            <div class="item_text small-9 large-9 columns">
                POS area is neat and well organized 
                  <!-- br--><p>No clutter around POS - Check card readers 
<br>Bills $20.00 and larger and checks under till and neatly organized</p>
            </div>
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <div class="item_scoring">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item_score item-7 small-6 columns">     
                        <input id="survey_scores_score_item" name="survey[scores][score_item]" placeholder="1" type="text">
                        <input as="hidden" id="survey_scores_inspection_id" name="survey[scores][inspection_id]" type="hidden" value="1">   
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_hiscore item-7 small-6 columns">
                        / 1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div> 
              <div class="item enclosure row"> 
                    <div class="item_text total small-9 large-9 columns">
                        Total:
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_scoring item_scoring_total small-3 total columns">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="item_score item_score_total small-6 columns">
                                XX
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_hiscore total small-6 columns">
                                / 1
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>    
      <h3>Safety</h3>
  <div class="my_group">
        <div class="item_enclosure row">
            <div class="item_text small-9 large-9 columns">
                Attendant wearing gloves 
            </div>
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <div class="item_scoring">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item_score item-10 small-6 columns">    
                        <input id="survey_scores_score_item" name="survey[scores][score_item]" placeholder="8" type="text">
                        <input as="hidden" id="survey_scores_inspection_id" name="survey[scores][inspection_id]" type="hidden" value="1">  
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_hiscore item-10 small-6 columns">
                        / 8
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div> 
        <div class="item_enclosure row">
            <div class="item_text small-9 large-9 columns">
                Proper Lifting by attendants 
            </div>
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <div class="item_scoring">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item_score item-11 small-6 columns">    
                        <input id="survey_scores_score_item" name="survey[scores][score_item]" placeholder="5" type="text">
                        <input as="hidden" id="survey_scores_inspection_id" name="survey[scores][inspection_id]" type="hidden" value="1">  
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_hiscore item-11 small-6 columns">
                        / 5
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div> 
        <div class="item_enclosure row">
            <div class="item_text small-9 large-9 columns">
                Area in and around DEC clean 
            </div>
            <div class="small-3 columns">
                <div class="item_scoring">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="item_score item-9 small-6 columns">     
                        <input id="survey_scores_score_item" name="survey[scores][score_item]" placeholder="1" type="text">
                        <input as="hidden" id="survey_scores_inspection_id" name="survey[scores][inspection_id]" type="hidden" value="1">   
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_hiscore item-9 small-6 columns">
                        / 1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  
            </div>              
        </div> 
              <div class="item enclosure row"> 
                    <div class="item_text total small-9 large-9 columns">
                        Total:
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_scoring item_scoring_total small-3 total columns">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="item_score item_score_total small-6 columns">
                                XX
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_hiscore total small-6 columns">
                                / 14
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
</div>   
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Edit survey">
</form>
    </main>    
</body></html>
```

The answers are helping me to see that I'm unable to select a specific tag within an h3 because it's its own element. so I've modified the markup so that each logical grouping is within a div with a class of "my_group". I'm trying to get my script in Fiddle to work on totaling up all the inputs found within these div's. I need to find a way to logically have this script find within these logical units.

My updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sam452/Yk33t/7/

I hope someone is kind enough to educate me on how I should scope this and get this script to work as expected.

Comment: Your markup has nothing inside the `<h3>`, and obviously no `<h3>` elements contained inside `<input>`s, so neither of your selectors make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: That's equivalent to `$('h3 input#survey_scores_score_item')`

Comment: you don't need to wrap your selector with `'`. Just go `$("input#survey_scores_score_item, h3")`

Comment: It's just CSS selector syntax, so `"h3 #survey_scores_score_item"` (all one selector, with a space) is all you need.

Comment: Please review your fiddle you don't have anything but a sentence inside the <h3> indentation isn't enough for anything to contain any other thing in HTML.. actually anything contained should be place between the open and the close tags

Comment: Thank you. Logically, when a user inputs a number in the input fields, the script should total up all the indicated input fields *within* each <h3> tag, because each set of totals are grouped within the <h3> tags. Of course, an input in the second group should not be in the sum of the first group, or any other. Thus, my attempt to scope using an <h3>.

Comment: @sam452 To be "within" a tag means to be between the opening tag (`<h3>`) and the closing tag (`</h3>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `$('input#survey_scores_score_item', 'h3')` is equivalent to `$('h3').find('input#survey_scores_score_item')`.

Since the `h3` contains no children you will never select any elements.  If you already have the `id` of the element there is no need for placing the selector in any sort of context, just use: `$("#survey_scores_score_item")`.

Comment: @War10ck I wanted it to really stand out, so I used find.  Not to mention we already have the id of the element we want to select...

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't even pay attention to the id selector alone. +1

Comment: Well, if the JavaScript code doesn't know for sure that the element with that id will actually be inside an `<h3>` tag, it might make sense.

Comment: This answer and the comments above are correct in pointing out a fundamental misunderstanding of selection in jQuery. For completeness, my reworked solution can be found here: https://github.com/sam452/inspector/commit/b24d8ae254b6356896bcabfb11e4fd00a96a94d6